# How to fix "An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. "

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlclient

I am trying to host an Asp.Net website with a database. It's giving me an error, of can't open the database

I have tried to change the connection string but to no avail.

This is the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="WebSqlConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=MXOLISI\MSSQLSERVER2;,1432 ;database=NCEDA2014;User ID=NCEDA14;Password=7n63rDYtp38Ymfd;"/>
</connectionStrings>`
```

[image: exception]
[image: another exception]

I expect for the webpage to open the default page

Comment: Try to test login with username pasword

Comment: Why do you have a semicolon and comma before 1432?

Comment: I hope you have not posted your actual user name and password in that connection string.  If so, the whole world can see them!  You may wish to remove them from the post.  What is the `,1432 ;` part of your connection string.  Go to https://www.connectionstrings.com/ and make sure your connect string is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly says your connection string has a wrong format.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WebSqlConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MXOLISI\MSSQLSERVER2,1432;
       database=NCEDA2014; User ID=NCEDA14;Password=7n63rDYtp38Ymfd;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

You placed port number after semicolon which is not correct, it should be after server name.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps first:

1. Open SQL server and try to access the database with the credentials mentioned in the config file. If it works fine, follow next step.
2. Check your connection string. Use below code as you are having issue in your connection string:

   ```
   <add key="myConnectionString" value="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
   ```